# Help identifying a film involving people living in regulated areas of the planet, get shot if they try to escape

Tags: story-identification

I vividly remember a film from when I was a kid and I keep wondering if anyone knows what it was.

I remember that all the characters (I think they were humans) had a light in the center of their heads. They had to stay in regulated areas of the planet. If they tried to escape, they were shot by the guards and the weapons turned them into to some sort of chocolate milkshake-looking mush.

As far as I recall the hero did escape (possibly with the love interest) and his light went out but he survived?

**Ring any bells?**

Comment: Do you mean *has a **light** in the center of their head*

Comment: And since we don't know your age, and therefore when you were a kid, how long ago was it you saw this film?  5 years?  50 years?

Comment: Almost _Logan's Run_, but they had lights in their hands.

Comment: I thought the light was in the head but might be the hand I'll check that out thanks fruibat. I'm 40 so I guess I watched it 30 years ago - ish

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/199541/movie-about-a-civilization-with-limited-life-span-and-an-integrated-light-indica (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 3):

Per @Andrew Murphy's answer, this certainly sounds a lot like the film "Logan's Run" (which you can watch [in full](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xyi3g6_logan-s-run-movie-part-1_lifestyle) on DailyMotion).

**Characters wore a special mark in their heads.**

- All the characters had a glowing chip in their ***hands.***

**Everyone had to stay in a designated areas**

- Yep. They all lived in a giant dome

**If they tried to escape, they were shot by the guards**

- Yes. [Run, runner!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EoKz-ilaZiA)

**The bodies were turned into "milkshake"**

- Check. They were [sprayed to get rid of the remains](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSkj8GxcOoI). It's pretty gory stuff.

**The main character escapes with his love interest**

- Logan does indeed leave the city with Jessica.

**His light goes out, but he survives.**

- Yup, that happened when he left the confines of the city