# Movie about a civilization with limited life span and an integrated light indicator in their hands showing when they were about to die

Tags: story-identification, movie

I recall when I was young (about 30+ years ago) I saw on TV a movie about a civilization (possibly humans in the future)  with limited life span (they died young) and if I recall correctly, an integrated red light indicator in their hands showing when they were about to die. When the light indicator turned on or turned off (I dont recall exactly) it meant they were about to die soon.

Does anyone have an idea which movie it could be?

Comment: Renew!! RENEW!!

Comment: [Run, Runner...!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EoKz-ilaZiA)

Comment: 7 years ago - https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1637688/ - sounds similar. "immortal" and no natural death... but timer on arm that counts down. work to earn more time.

Comment: The "hermetic ultimate civilization" theme was popular back then, maybe Michael Moorcock's "The Dancers at the End of Time" inspired some of it. Another was "Zardoz", where the barbarian Sean Connery was introduced into the city to destroy it, reboot evolution by breeding with Vanessa Redgrave in the aftermath and get humanity striving again. In retrospect, maybe it was a commentary on communism too.

Comment: It's not the answer, but the book '_The Quantum Thief_' shows a society which toys with a similar concept, with time being used as currency where you can transfer it between each other.

Comment: Just reading the title I was sure you were askign about In TIme

Comment: It is traditional for our people to view this documentary when they turn 30. You have to wear a special outfit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [looking for title of young adult book of city under glass dome and all wore identification tracking bracelets](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107077/looking-for-title-of-young-adult-book-of-city-under-glass-dome-and-all-wore-iden)

Comment: The proposed duplicate has no accepted answer, while this question does.

Comment: Before I read the full question, I thought the title was referring to "In Time". I thought the OP got confused by how young people _looked_ when they died, and thought they actually _were_ that young.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You're describing [Logan's Run](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logan%27s_Run_(film)).

> In the year 2274, the remnants of human civilization live in a sealed
>   city contained beneath a cluster of geodesic domes, a utopia run by a
>   computer that takes care of all aspects of their life, including
>   reproduction. The citizens live a hedonistic life but in order to
>   maintain the population levels everyone must undergo the rite of
>   "Carrousel" when they reach the age of 30. There, they are vaporized
>   and ostensibly "renewed". To track this, each person is implanted at
>   birth with a "life-clock" crystal in the palm of their hand that
>   changes color as they get older and begins blinking as they approach
>   their "Last Day". Most residents accept this promise of rebirth, but
>   those who do not and attempt to flee the city are known as "Runners".
>   An elite team of policemen known as "Sandmen", outfitted in
>   predominantly black uniforms and serving in an agency of the city
>   called "Deep Sleep", are assigned to pursue and terminate Runners as
>   they try to escape.

Comment: The 2011 film In Time (https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1637688/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_24) takes the life-clock idea but adds the ability for people to "earn" more time.

Comment: @user14111  - The [script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Logan's-Run.html) say "Carousel"

Comment: @user14111 - Mildly interesting story actually. There's a typo on the opening text of the film (or at least, the word is spelled the non-Standard French way) and there's been a running edit war on Wikipedia over it; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQpIAx2Gzik

Comment: "Is Logan still on his run?" - Vic Reeves (Big Night Out)

Comment: "Carrousel" is an _acceptable_ variant of "carousel" (well, according to at least one American Heritage edition, which is probably just fuel to the fire). The former is basically the French spelling, so one presumes that it was borrowed from that form at some point before being simplified. But this would be a question for another SE.

Comment: @jdv - All signs point to it simply being a typo (since it was spelled differently in [the script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Logan's-Run.html) ***and*** in the [TV show episode "Carousel"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0635119/)), but there's always the possibility that it was intentional for some reason.

Comment: Lord have mercy, Jenny Agutter was so hot...

Comment: @valorum maybe, but given how many revisions a script goes through, and given that this was probably revised several times and then typed up by different people over several years, it is just as likely it was as intended as the alternate spelling.

Comment: @jdv thank God they don't know about "fuze"...

Comment: We'd have to kick them to the kerb like an old tyre to save our honour.

Answer (score 13):

This is the 1976 film or 1977 TV series *Logan's Run*.  The post-apocalyptic inhabitants of a domed city have crystal life clocks embedded in their palms.  When they reach 30 years old (21 in the novel), the clock starts blinking and the must participate in a ritual called 'Carousel' to continue living.  In actuality, nobody survives it.

Comment: This does mention the TV series as well. Admittedly, if the OP actually saw it 30 years ago, the movie is the much more likely candidate.

Comment: "ritual called 'Carousel' to continue living" - I don't recall anyone believing that Carousel was anything other than a death sentence but I could be wrong

Comment: Going from memory, but I believe there's a nominal possibility of "renewal" (surviving the Carousel), but as the film progresses Logan realizes that this is a myth.

Comment: @NKCampbell belief was well implied. There was a novel as well you know.  I would have thought this was mandatory viewing after the Family Guy reference. Amazing how this predicted Tinder so well too. It did borrow a bit from POTA and Soylent Green here and there too, the Univac style computer and the Brave New World style breeding made it almost generic. Population control and the eventual decay of the city were almost mandatory plotlines.

Comment: What in hell is POTA?

Comment: @user89108 I am guessing Planet of the Apes.